# Grant Privileges in Oracle 10g

Tags: database, oracle

I am new to databases. Here I have logged in the user account:System

I then create a new user raj using the following command

```
create user raj identified by raj
```

Then I connected to the user raj using following command

```
grant connect to raj
```

Here I am granting privileges on the table client_master to raj

```
grant all on client_master to raj
```

Now I want to select the contents of table client_master

```
select * from raj.client_master
```

but it is giving an error that such table does not exist.

Comment: "grant connect" does not "connect to the user", it merely gives the user the _right_ to connect to the database. You need to actually login as `raj` and run something like `create table client_master (...)` as user `raj`, otherwise there won't be such a table. But `raj` also needs the `create table`privilege for that, only having the `connect` privilege is not enough

Comment: but how then one user can grant priveleges ro another??

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google and you would find out that the select right is as simple as *select*.

```
grant select on client_master to raj;
```

However, it is not the real problem as when executing this command `grant all on client_master to raj` the *select* privilege is already included.

So here are the possibilities why you get this error :

- The table does not exist (you need to create it).
- It is in another schema, and you did not specify it.
- You made a typo when writing *client_master*.

My guess is that you created the table in sys schema (which is really a bad idea btw) so the problem is the option 2 in the one I listed.

Try

```
select * from sys.client_master;
```

Note that if you don't want to always specify the prefix, you can create a synonym.

```
create synonym raj.client_master for sys.client_master;
```

Then

```
select * from client_master;
```

Would work.

Answer (score -1):

Try running below command -

> **GRANT EXECUTE ON Find_Value TO smith;**

This may help you to resolve your issue.